# To get an optimizing solution for VRP using Graphhopper/jsprit

Tags: graphhopper, jsprit

While solving Vehicle Routing problem using Graphhopper/jsprit, For example , we get the solution as follows

```
Pickup1 - job1 
Pickup2 - job2
Pickup3 - job3
Delivery1 - job1
Delivery2 - job2
Pickup4 - job4
```

So the problem i have with this solution is, It is going for Pickup of job4 eventhough - job3 is still in the Vehicle. My ultimate aim would be to go for pickup  only when the vehicle is empty.Also If a vehicle isn't going to be delivered before another pickup then it shouldn't have been picked up in the first place(For ex: job 3 in above example).

So any suggestions to help with the possible Hard type constraint to satisfy the above conditions? Please suggest.I will update any further details if needed.

Comment: Are job1, job2, job3, job4 vehicle ids?

Comment: yes. They are Job IDs